# JPA composite primary key from foreign keys with property access

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

**I'm a novice in JPA please stay with me.**

Apparently there is no question about how to create a composite primary key from foreign keys in a property access way.

**Question**

If I use the property access type as in the example below, do I have to define getters and setters for the referenced FKs as well ?

I did not think that that's the case but the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) of Java EE6 does so.

[Oracle® Containers for J2EE Enterprise JavaBeans Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm)

> A composite primary key class has the following characteristics:
>
> - It is a POJO class.
> - It must be public and must have a public no-argument constructor.
> - **If you use property-based access, the properties of the primary key class must be public or protected.**
> - It must be serializable.
> - It must define equals and hashCode methods.
> - The semantics of value equality for these methods must be consistent with the database equality for the database types to which the key is mapped.
>
> You can make the composite primary key class either an embedded class
> owned by the entity class, or a nonembedded class whose fields you map
> to multiple fields or properties of the entity class. In the latter
> case, the names of primary key fields or properties in the composite
> primary key class and those of the entity class must correspond and
> their types must be the same.

I modified this example because I want to use FKs.

```
Example 7-2 Embeddable Composite Primary Key Class

@Embeddable
public class EmployeePK implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private long id;

    public EmployeePK() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) name.hashCode() + id;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof EmployeePK)) return false;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        EmployeePK pk = (EmployeePK) obj;
        return pk.id == id && pk.name.equals(name);
    }
}

Example 7-3 JPA Entity With an Embedded Composite Primary Key Class

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    EmployeePK primaryKey;
 
    public Employee() {
    }
 
    @EmbeddedId
    public EmployeePK getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }
 
    public void setPrimaryKey(EmployeePK pk) {
        primaryKey = pk;
    }
 
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("id")
    private classWithPKid fkobject1;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("name")
    private classWithPKname fkobject2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, but it's not getters and setters - as a rule of thumb you can assume that in JPA everything needs those. Please add all your entities to the question

Comment: Is the above modified example sufficient ?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer. Question one is confused, question two might have more than one answer. Try it! This site works best if you have a concrete problem with well defined success criteria (like "answer explains how to make it work when it didn't before")

Comment: Okay I will try to define only one clear question.

Comment: Did your code work?  Best way is just to run it and post the exception.  And the spec seems clear- what you have should work.  MapsId is very different then the ID annotation - you are just telling JPA that the two mappings use the same field underneath.  You might also do away with your embedded ID and just mark the ManyToOne mappings as the ID field, using your embedded class as a pk class instead.

Comment: currently I have another problem with EJB injection, as soon as that works I can test my entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JPA Spec (2.3.2) - **Explicit Access Type**

> **When Access(PROPERTY) is applied to an entity class**, mapped superclass, or embeddable class, mapping annotations may be placed on the properties of that class, and **the persistence provider runtime accesses persistent state via the properties defined by that class**. All properties that are not annotated with the Transient annotation are persistent. When Access(PROPERTY) is applied to such a class, it is possible to selectively designate individual attributes within the class for instance variable access. **To specify a persistent instance variable for access by the persistence provider runtime, that instance variable must be designated Access(FIELD)**. **The behavior is undefined if mapping annotations are placed on any instance variables defined by the class for which Access(FIELD) is not specified**. Persistent state inherited from superclasses is accessed in accordance with the access types of those superclasses.

### JPA Spec (2.3.3) - **Access Type of an Embeddable Class**

> **The access type of an embeddable class is determined by the access type of the entity class**, mapped superclass, or embeddable class **in which it is embedded** (including as a member of an element collection) independent of whether the access type of the containing class has been explicitly specified or defaulted. A different access type for an embeddable class can be specified for that embeddable class by means of the Access annotation as described above.

When the AccessType is set to PROPERTY for an entity class, the provider will use the methods to get the persistent state and mapping data. The persistence provider is not obligated to look for mapping annotations on fields when the AccessType for the class is PROPERTY. Also, note that AccessType is inherited by the Embedded class, which is why EmployeePK needs to define the getters/setters as well. Based on what it says in the spec, when the entity class is using Access(PROPERTY), you should do one of the following:

1. Define getter/setter methods for the FK fields and place the mappings on the getter methods

   Example:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   public class Employee {
       private EmployeePK primaryKey;

       private ClassWithPKid fkobject1;

       @EmbeddedId
       public EmployeePK getPrimaryKey() {
           return primaryKey;
       }

       @ManyToOne
       @MapsId("id")
       public ClassWithPKid getFkobject1() {
           return fkobject1;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or, explicitly define Access(FIELD) on the persistent field

   Example:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   public class Employee {
       private EmployeePK primaryKey;

       @ManyToOne
       @MapsId("id")
       @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
       private ClassWithPKid fkobject1;

       @EmbeddedId
       public EmployeePK getPrimaryKey() {
           return primaryKey;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Meanwhile  I used example one and thanks to you I'm now certain that this is was correct, so far no errors with eclipse link 2.5 and JPA 2.0 (just one initial test though).  Also since the accessType is inherited I do not need to place the AccessType.PROPERTY above the Embeddable PK class right ?

Comment: @MADforFUNandHappy Correct. Access type of an embeddable class is determined by the access type of the entity class in which it is embedded. You should not need to explicitly define this on the Embeddable class.